# Sprite keeps moving off screen

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am practicing with SpriteKit with simple player movement when the user tilts the device. However I want the player to no be able to go off the screen, but when I try to change the y position to the frame.MaxY(or minY) it just keeps going. The code below is what I call inside the update function.

```
 if let accelerometerData = motionManager.accelerometerData {
            player.position.y += CGFloat(accelerometerData.acceleration.x * 50)

            if(player.position.y < frame.minY) {
                player.position.y = frame.minY
            } else if(player.position.y > frame.maxY) {
                player.position.y = frame.maxY
            }
        }
```

Comment: you may need to account for the players own size  `player.position.y > frame.maxY - player.size.height` etc.

Comment: That keeps it on the screen, but the sprite stutters when it hits

Comment: you must also take the size into account when resetting the position `player.position.y = frame.maxY + player.size.height`

Comment: Awesome! I actually read your first comment wrong and already had the second part. Thank you it worked. IF you want you can post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the size of the player into account like so (pseudocode)

```
if let accelerometerData = motionManager.accelerometerData {
            player.position.y += CGFloat(accelerometerData.acceleration.x * 50)

            if (player.position.y < frame.minY) {
                player.position.y = frame.minY    // <- maybe need some adjustment here too
            } else if(player.position.y > frame.maxY - player.size.height) {
                player.position.y = frame.maxY - player.size.height
            }
        }
```